# PHP foreach loop every fifth item

Tags: php

I have a simple foreach loop like:

```
foreach ( $posts as $index => $posts )
```

and also a counter:

```
if( $index % 5 + 1 == 5 ) {
//do something 
}
```

I have 15 posts per page and it should do something every fifth item but NOT on the last but how do I do that?

So it becomes:

```
POST
POST
POST
POST
POST
DO SOMETHING
POST
POST
POST
POST
POST
DO SOMETHING
POST
POST
POST
POST
POST
```

Comment: I assume you know the max index, then change if condition to something like ($index % 5 + 1 == 5) && ($index < SIZE)

Comment: See "FizzBuzz"? This is the *same* thing (actually, it's less complicated)... you just need to know the conditional for "last", which has already been covered elsewhere, and combine it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know, you have 15 posts, and need every 5th but not the last...
That means you need to 'make something' with the 5th and 10th one, am i right?
So why not check that?

```
if($index == 4 || $index == 9)
```

Comment: Exactly this, this is far more readable than `$index % 5 + 1 == 5 && $index != 15`, special cases should be special.

Comment: That's because you're starting your $index at 0

Comment: Yes, 4 and 9, my bad :) arrays start with 0, so the last item is number 14.

Comment: The simplest answer is usually the best

Answer (score 4):

```
if( $index % 5 + 1 == 5 && $index != 14) {
//do something 
}
```

Change your conditional so that the $index does not equal the last index in your array.  Whether that's 14 or 15 (depending on if you start at 0 or 1).

Comment: Still does the 'do something after the 15th item!

Comment: Does your `$index` start at 0 or 1? Change it to `$index != 14` if $index starts at 0

Answer (score 1):

Check the range operator.. very useful for this sort of situation.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

foreach (range(0, $index, 5) as $number) {
    // do something with $posts[$number]
}
```

Comment: How would this be used/useful here?

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't need associative arrays:

```
$posts=array(a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a);

for($i=0;$i<count($posts);$i++)
{
if($i % 5 + 1 == 5 && $i != count($posts) - 1)
{
echo $i." as ".$posts[$i];
}
}
```

This will remove every last post, and only echo every fifth post.